# Проблема с запуском скриптов Node.JS на Windows

Tags: node.js

Не могу запустить скрипт Node.JS через консоль, вылезает ошибка:

```
Error: Failed opening file C:\Users\╨б╨╡╤А╨│╨╡╨╣\AppData\Roaming\Code\logs\20180120T184631\main.log for writing: No such file or directory
        at RotatingLogger (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\node_modules\spdlog\index.js:16:3)
        at Object.t.createLogService (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:182:426)
        at q (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:407:340)
        at G (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:411:127)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:411:922)
        at Function.t._safeInvokeFunction (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js:19:213)
        at Function.t._invokeFactory (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js:19:460)
        at t.complete (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js:19:731)
        at s._onModuleComplete (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js:30:70)
        at s._onModuleComplete (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js:30:314)
```

Ошибка от содержания не зависит, хоть `console.log();` пиши, хоть сложный код.
Перетаскивать скрипт в корень диска C:\ тоже пробовал, бесполезно.

Comment: Пользователь windows на русском? Попробуйте создать пользователя только с латинскими символами и на нем запустить

Comment: Похоже, что проблема в том, что у вас имя пользователя на русском и из-за этого node падает. Хотя этого быть не должно, т.к. node использует utf-8. Скорее всего это баг ноды, попробуйте создать issue у них и точно всё описать.